# How do I select the next item in an array when a user clicks on a button?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am making quiz using 4 buttons to answer the questions (I have 6 questions in total).

How do I get the next set of questions from my array? It looks like this:

```
var questions = [{
       question: "the question!".
       answer1: "choice1",
       answer2: "choice2",
       answer3: "choice3",
       answer4: "choice4",
       correct: "choice3",

}}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error (`}}` at the end instead of `}]`) in your array definition and your array only contains one item. Please provide more details about how you're displaying the question and how you're currently trying to select the next question.

Answer (score 0):

Just track the current index in the array, and when they click, increment the index.  And then I'd just have a `render` method which takes the index as a parameter.  Something like:

```js
const questions = [{
       question: "the question!",
       answer1: "choice1",
       answer2: "choice2",
       answer3: "choice3",
       answer4: "choice4",
       correct: "choice3"

}, {
       question: "the next question!",
       answer1: "A",
       answer2: "B",
       answer3: "C",
       answer4: "D",
       correct: "C"
}];

var currentQuestionIndex = 0;

const c = document.getElementById('content');

const render = (idx) => {
    const q = questions[idx];
    c.innerHTML = `<strong>${q.question}</strong>
        <p><label><input name="q" type="radio"/>${q.answer1}</label>
        <p><label><input name="q" type="radio"/>${q.answer2}</label>
        <p><label><input name="q" type="radio"/>${q.answer3}</label>
        <p><label><input name="q" type="radio"/>${q.answer4}</label>
    `;
}

render(currentQuestionIndex);

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    currentQuestionIndex = (currentQuestionIndex + 1) % questions.length;
    render(currentQuestionIndex);
});
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>

<button id="btn">Next</button>
```